# Remove extra space at the bottom of the last page, when using tablesorter pagination

Tags: html, css

When a number of rows on the last page is small it leaves space below the table. On a "full" page, there is no space.
Also,

Pics (the html background set to green just for demonstration)

[image]

No extra space

[image]

I played with min-height/max-height/height. Couldn't get close to what I would like to see.

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

html {
  /* min-height: 100%; */
  /* min-height: 200px; */
  background-color: green;
}
```

Also been logging height for `body` and `html` in my .js.

```
console.log(`BODY: ${$('body').height()}`);
console.log(`HTML: ${$('html').height()}`);
```

And there is probably something that I don't understand, because it shows that height of html = height of body - margin-top for every page of the table. I thought html height will be bigger, and then I will be able to set the height via JQuery. Also if I set really small(like 200px) `max-height` for `html` it doesn't seem to have any effect, but I definitely can see the difference if I set a big `min-height` for html, like 1600px or something. Is there some global `min-size` that couldn't be less than some value?

I don't think the table styling or some Tablesorter options have anything to do with it. Let me know if some additional info will be useful.

EDIT.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edvard_munch/ybvjeqh7/21/)

[example](https://hockey.fantasysports.yahoo.com/hockey/17689/players?status=A&pos=G&cut_type=33&stat1=S_S_2018&myteam=0&sort=AR&sdir=1&count=125) of the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Its works:

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin:0;
  min-height:100%;
}

html {
  background-color: green;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: not exactly, I'm now thinking that what I want doesn't make sense and probably not possible, because HTML page shouldn't be that small. In the example I've linked there is footer and a very big navbar, that probably why it doesn't have any space at the bottom. I should do a footer and some other stuff on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation of footer:

CSS:

```
@supports (display: grid) {
    body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 3.5rem  auto fit-content(8rem);
        grid-template-areas: "header"
                             "main"
                             "footer";
        padding-top: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


main {
    grid-area: main;
}


.main-footer {
    background: black;
    padding: 2rem;
    grid-area: footer;
}

.main-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="main-header">
            This is a header!
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="main">
            This is a main!
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="main-footer">
        <nav>
             <span>This is a your footer!</span>
        </nav>
    </footer>

</body>
```